# TeXstudio unable to notice different files that have the same name

Tags: texstudio, filesystem-access

I have duplicated a project contains "./TeX_files/chapter01..05". Now I am editing the new one. However, when I try to open "./TeX_files/chapterX" from the old one, TeXstduio opens "./TeX_files/chapterX" from the new one (set as root).

I think it does not check the full path of the selected file on the "Structure" panel, it is only checking the filename. To open the file I want, I have to set the root document. Is there any way to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Options" -> "Root Document" -> "Detect Automatically Root Document".

It is anwered by "sunderme" on [Github Issue](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1504#issuecomment-785300507).